# jQuery selector to target the control right before current element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select the element right BEFORE current element. The current element is a hyperlink which when clicked appends some text to the "target" which is just before the hyperlink.

These controls are in asp:repeater so the same sequence gets repeated over and over and every hyperlink should be able to identify the element just above it.

here is my DOM screenshot

[image]

I just need to know how to select the element this way ! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `previousSibling`:

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i=0, len=as.length;i<len;i++){
    as[i].onclick = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var previous;
        if (this.previousSibling.nodeName == '#text') {
            // the previousSibling was a textnode, comprising of the whitespace between elements
            previous = this.previousSibling.previousSibling;
        }
        else {
            previous = this.previousSibling;
        }
        previous.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fuaUe/1/).

Or use jQuery's `prev()`:

```
$('a').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prev('div').css('background-color','yellow');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fuaUe/).

References:

- [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/event.preventDefault).
- [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeName).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.previousSibling).

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to be of help! =) ...though I think the `if` in the first code sample could/should be simplified somehow... =/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?: http://api.jquery.com/next/

**EDIT**: http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: thats the "immediately following" element selector. I need the "previous" selector. :)

Comment: So clarify your question, please. It should read *select the element right **before** current*, not **after**, right? I got the same, obviously false impression as Ryan Casas from 1st reading.

Comment: But now you have your answers. No problem, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `prev` is the solution you want.  Just to answer your question, if you want a *selector* for that, you could build one yourself like this:

```
$.expr[':'].prev = function(o) {
    return $(o).prev();
};
```

And use it like:

```
$('a:prev').someMethod();  // which works exactly like $('a').prev().someMethod
```